# Pulling custom attribute of an image URL by JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a static page that has a dynamic image view.
I'm trying to pull only the image URL and not the image it self.

```
  <li class="image
             item itemNo0 selected maintain-height"><span class="a-list-item">
                <span class="a-declarative" data-action="main-image-click" data-main-image-click="{}">
                    <div id="imgTagWrapperId" class="imgTagWrapper">

                        <img alt="Libbey Vina Stemless Red Wine Glasses, 16.75-Ounce, Clear, Set of 4" src="  <!-- probably some hash function or something like that --> 


" data-old-hires=""  class="a-dynamic-image  a-stretch-vertical" id="landingImage" data-a-dynamic-image="{&quot;http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/11T7HAGXXVL.jpg&quot;:[160,160]}" style="max-width:160px;max-height:160px;">
                    </div>
                </span>
            </span></li>
```

i want to get only this link :

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/11T7HAGXXVL.jpg
```

here is the web page:

```
http://www.amazon.com/Libbey-Stemless-Glasses-16-75-Ounce-Clear/dp/B00KIG3UZ8/ref=sr_1_1?s=kitchen&ie=UTF8&qid=1413005036&sr=1-1&keywords=glass
```

was trying to use `$("#landingImage").value("data-a-dynamic-image");`

but it start pulling a lot of info from the web site it self.
I just need the link as a text.

what should i use?

Comment: By the way, `<<<<` is not a valid `HTML` comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `data-a-image` attribute seems to be an object with the URL as the key.
Try this:

```
var data = $("#landingImage").data("a-dynamic-image");
for(key in data)
    var url = key;
```

This will return the URL.

Explanation:
You can access any data attribute using the `data` function. For example: `data-length` can be accessed using `data('length')`. Similarly you can use `attr('data-length')`. There is no function called `value()`! It's the `val()`function returns you the node value, and not the attribute value. Think of it as returning the text written in a span and not the span's attributes e.g. id, class etc.

Comment: Nice! can you explain a bit ? :) what was wrong with what i did?

Comment: Wait, let me add some explanation!

Answer (score 0):

TRY $("#landingImage").getAttribute("data-a-dynamic-image");